# In Thymeleaf how can you use separate resolvers for HTML and JavaScript to copy JavaScript from a file into the generated HTML

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, templates, thymeleaf

I am creating a Proof of Concept program to later be brought into a larger project. Thymeleaf seemed like a good template engine to try (Natural Templates with active development) and mostly it seems to fit but I have been having the following issue.

**Goal:** Take JSON and generate an HTML file that will work offline for report viewing. Currently I am just trying to convert a premade HTML template into a single HTML page with no external references to other files or the internet.

**Problem:** I can't get all Javascript to resolve correctly inside the template resolver.

**Detailed description:** I have attempted to keep my Javascript and my HTML in separate directories. That way my Javascript can use the '.js' suffix and my HTML can use the '.html' suffix.

In order to do this I created two resolvers, one for HTML and one for JS. I have seen similar things done for HTML fragments and that seemed to work for other people.

The problem is that my JS resolver never seems to get used when it hits the `<script th:include="jquery.min></script"`part of my demo.tpl.html file. 
I figured that because the `.setOrder(1)` is on the HTML resolver and the `.setOrder(2)` is on the JS resolver that when it can't find a 'jquery.min' template from the first resolver it would simply query the second resolver for such a template.

I attempted to do the resolution with the JS resolver set as the first resolver and it attempted to resolve 'demo.js' (which doesn't exist) instead of failing and checking the second resolver in the list which would have a 'demo.tpl.html' available to resolve.

It seems as if it only ever uses the first Resolver and the second resolver is ignored.

**Relevant Environment Details:**

```
   ...
   <properties>
      <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
   </properties>
   ...
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
```

Also, I am not using spring, this is a command line tool and I wanted to keep as light as possible and I didn't see the need for spring.

The type of Resolver I am using is a FileTemplateResolver since I am not using a servlet to resolve HTML directly to a browser.

**File Structure:**

[image: File Structure of Project]

**GitHub Link:** https://github.com/njfife/JsonToHtmlReportGenerator

**The commit at the time of the question:** 619fb96

**ApplicationStart.java (main):**

```
public class ApplicationStart {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        ... stuff ...
        JsonConverter jsonConverter = new JsonConverter();
        String html = jsonConverter.render(); // This is what fails
        System.out.println(html);
        ... stuff ..
    }
}
```

**JsonConverter.java:**

```
public class JsonConverter {

    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
    private StandardMessageResolver messageResolver;
    private Properties properties;
    private Context context;
    private ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    // MUCH OF THE TOP OF THIS IS PROBABLY NOT RELATED TO THE ISSUE
    // SKIP TO WHERE THE TEMPLATE RESOLVERS ARE BUILT

    public JsonConverter() {
        // Set the template location
        File templates = 
            new File(classLoader.getResource("templates").getFile());
        // Get translation data
        this.properties = new Properties();
        this.context = new Context();
        // Hardcoded as spanish for testing
        this.context.setLocale(new Locale("es"));
        // This is all translation and message stuff, probably not
        // an issue in this case.
        try {
            StringBuilder defaultFileName = new StringBuilder();
            defaultFileName.append("messages");
            if(!context.getLocale().equals(Locale.ENGLISH)) {
                defaultFileName.append("_");
                defaultFileName.append(context.getLocale().toString());
            }
            defaultFileName.append(".properties");
            InputStream propertiesStream = classLoader
                .getResourceAsStream(defaultFileName.toString());
            this.properties.load(propertiesStream);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }

        // FROM HERE DOWN IS PROBALLY THE ISSUE

        this.templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();

        // Build the HTML resolver
        FileTemplateResolver htmlFileTemplateResolver 
           = new FileTemplateResolver();
        htmlFileTemplateResolver
            .setPrefix(templates.getAbsolutePath() + "/html/");
        htmlFileTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".tpl.html");
        htmlFileTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        htmlFileTemplateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        htmlFileTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        htmlFileTemplateResolver.setOrder(1); // Set as primary
        messageResolver = new StandardMessageResolver();
        messageResolver.setDefaultMessages(this.properties);
        templateEngine.setMessageResolver(messageResolver);

        FileTemplateResolver javascriptFileTemplateResolver 
            = new FileTemplateResolver();
        javascriptFileTemplateResolver
            .setPrefix(templates.getAbsolutePath() + "/includes/");
        javascriptFileTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".js");
        javascriptFileTemplateResolver
            .setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
        javascriptFileTemplateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        javascriptFileTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        javascriptFileTemplateResolver.setOrder(2);
        // Resolve Resource Location
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlFileTemplateResolver);
        templateEngine
            .addTemplateResolver(javascriptFileTemplateResolver);
    }

    public String render() {
        // Testing programatic alteration of context
        context.setVariable("name", "Nathan");
        // THIS FAILS TO RENDER HTML WHEN WHEN INCLUDING JQUERY
        return templateEngine.process("demo", context);
    }
}
```

**Relevant HTML Template:**

```
... stuff ..
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <th:block>
        <script th:include="jquery.min"></script>
        <script th:include="highcharts.min"></script>
    </th:block>
    <h1>Chart Demo</h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p th:text="#{hello}"></p>
    <p th:text="${name}"></p>
    <p th:text="#{message}"></p>
    <p th:text="#{message.with.var(${name})}"></p>
</body>
... stuff ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TL;DL*** - If you want the templateEngine to switch resolvers when the source template file isn't in the current resolver's path you have to set the `checkExistence` flag to `true` by calling `yourTemplateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);`. If you don't do that it will attempt to resolve the template from the first resolver in your list even if there is no template with that file name in the path.

*Also, `th:include` is deprecated so don't use it, use `th:insert` or one of the other options instead.*

---

So, I decided to walk through the source code and find where it was deciding which templateResolver to use with which template and came across this block of code:

```
for (final ITemplateResolver templateResolver : configuration.getTemplateResolvers()) {

            final TemplateResolution templateResolution =
                    templateResolver.resolveTemplate(configuration, ownerTemplate, template, templateResolutionAttributes);
            if (templateResolution != null) {
                if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                    logger.trace(
                            "[THYMELEAF][{}] Template resolver match! Resolver \"{}\" will resolve template \"{}\"",
                            new Object[] {TemplateEngine.threadIndex(), templateResolver.getName(), LoggingUtils.loggifyTemplateName(template)});
                }
                return templateResolution;
            }

            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                    logger.trace(
                            "[THYMELEAF][{}] Skipping template resolver \"{}\" for template \"{}\"",
                            new Object[] {TemplateEngine.threadIndex(), templateResolver.getName(), LoggingUtils.loggifyTemplateName(template)});
            }

        }
```

For some reason the template resolution was comming back as 'NOT NULL' even though there was no file present.

Digging into the `resolveTemplate` function I found this conditional:

```
if (this.checkExistence && !templateResource.exists()) { // will only check if flag set to true
    return null;
}
```

Adding `htmlFileTemplateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);`

And changing my "demo.tpl.html" file to use `th:insert` instead of `th:include` fixed everything.

```
<th:block>
    <script th:insert="jquery.min"></script>
    <script th:insert="highcharts.min"></script>
</th:block>
```

Not sure why exactly you need to tell the templateResolver that the existence of a template is a requirement for the resolver being a valid resolver for that template. At the very least I think the default should be true but I don't think mine is the standard use case so it's possible I am an outlier here.